# notification in iphone and android using as3

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I need to show notifications at specific time through the app(iphone and android app). The app is developed fully in as3. 
I have tried using adobe native extension for notification but it is working fine on android but not on iphone. here is a link to it http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/notification.html 
Can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer from here [Local Notifications with iOS 4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html) for iphone development.

Refrom from here [Android Notifications - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html) for android Development.